# Writing value to given filed in csv file using pandas or csv module

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Is there any way you can write value to specific place in given .csv file using pandas or csv module?

I have tried using csv_reader to read the file and find a line which fits my requirements though I couldn't figure out a way to switch value which is in the file to mine.

What I am trying to achieve here is that I have a spreadsheet of names and values. I am using JSON to update the values from the server and after that I want to update my spreadsheet also.

The latest solution which I came up with was to create separate sheet from which I will get updated data, but this one is not working, though there is no sequence in which the dict is written to the file.

```
def updateSheet(fileName, aValues):
    with open(fileName+".csv") as workingSheet:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(workingSheet,aValues.keys())
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(aValues)
```

I will appreciate any guidance and tips.

Comment: you have to read all data to memory. (ie. `df = pandas.read_csv()`), assign new value, and save all data to file (ie. `df.to_csv()`). In similar way you have to do with `csv` module.

Comment: It might work but I need to overwrite only specific fields (ie. 1st column and 5th). Another fields uses data from one another to calculate their value.

Comment: file is not list or dict - it will not resize place if you want put longer or shorter data. If you try to put longer data then it overwrite other cells, if you put shorter data then it leave part of older data. You have to read all in memory, change your 1st and 5th column, and write all again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to operate the specified csv file

```
import pandas as pd  
a = ['one','two','three']  
b = [1,2,3]  
english_column = pd.Series(a, name='english')  
number_column = pd.Series(b, name='number')  
predictions = pd.concat([english_column, number_column], axis=1)   
save = pd.DataFrame({'english':a,'number':b})  
save.to_csv('b.csv',index=False,sep=',')
```

[image]